# IBM Rhapsody enumeration limits

Tags: c++, rhapsody

I have created an enumeration type in IBM Rhapsody in C++ version 8.1.5

The code which the auto-coder creates is as follows:

```
enum MY_ENUM {
   ENUM_ITEM_1,
   ENUM_ITEM_2,
   ENUM_ITEM_3
};
```

I would like for Rhapsody to auto-generate definitions of the enumeration limits, such as:

```
#define MY_ENUM_START ENUM_ITEM_1
#define MY_ENUM_END ENUM_ITEM_2
#define MY_ENUM_SIZE ( MY_ENUM_END + 1U )
```

Does anyone know of an option to do this in Rhapsody?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, it turns out that there is no option to automate this in Rhapsody (v8.1.5).

Any of the standard manual approaches can be applied, ie. adding an extra enumeration to the end called MAX etc.